# OpenCV: Tracking movement of phone device

Tags: opencv, positioning

I'm looking to track of the phone device running my app has moved, and if so what direction. I'm thinking that the incoming frames from the camera would need to be analyzed to track movement?

I've looked around the internet and have not going much regarding this. Could somebody assist me or point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Huh? If you have an app running on a phone, why not get the position from the device's GPS?

Comment: I need something more accurate than GPS, which can be accurate up to 10m. I'm looking to have the device recognize movement,I could use gyro for direction. Acceleration isn't accurate for steps either

Comment: Your question needs to be much more specific else you are just asking for a recommendation for a tool, or off-site resource which is not permitted. What accuracy do you need? What sort of distances are you trying to measure? What for? What language? What OS?

Comment: I apologise for the vagueness. I'm using Unity3D to develop an Android game. I'm looking to detect when the user holding the device is moving and display that movement in a 3d world; with high accuracy (less than 1m of error). The accelerometer isn't an option as simply shaking the device may register as movement. I thought OpenCV may be the answer, perhaps you can compare frames to determine if movement occurred and when it has stopped. I'm looking for suggestions on how might this be done in OpenCV, or any other unity-related solution. Let me know if you need additional information.